# How would I check if a value is larger than nth value of list of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm looking to optimize this function:

```py
cache = dict()
def user_rec (userID,nmf_matrix=nmf_matrix,topic_df=topic_df):
    if userID in cache:
        return cache[userID]
    users=[]
    for l in topic_df.loc[topic_df['user_id']==userID].index:
        for j in range (nmf_matrix.shape[0]):
            if topic_df.iloc[j].user_id != userID:
                sim = np.dot(nmf_matrix[j,:],nmf_matrix[l,:])
                users.append((topic_df.iloc[j].user_id,sim))

    users.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    top_users=[]
    for top in users:
        if top not in top_users:
            top_users.append(top)
    top_users = top_users[0:3]
    cache[userID]=top_users

    return [top[0] for top in top_users]
```

One part that I've identified as something that could be slimmed down is to just keep the list of as the top users while I'm calculating sim. ie. keep the tuple with the larger sim value

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

I've tried something like this with no success.

```
sim = np.dot(nmf_matrix[j,:],nmf_matrix[l,:])
if (all([users[1] for x in users]>sim)):
    users = users
else:
    users.append((topic_df.iloc[j].user_id,sim))
    users.remove(min())
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some sample data to make the code runnable? As is it would be difficult to test answers.